# UIDeviceListener not working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uidevice

I am using UIDeviceListener-master (https://github.com/eldade/UIDeviceListener) class for fetching batteryCount, batterymaximumCapacity but its listner class never gets called.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(listenerDataUpdated:) name: kUIDeviceListenerNewDataNotification object:nil];
```

Please provide me solution for fetching battery details in iOS10.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working on iOS10, you can find more information on UIDeviceListener Github issues https://github.com/eldade/UIDeviceListener/issues/3

You can use IOKit:

```
mach_port_t iokitPort = 0;
CFMutableDictionaryRef properties;
IOMasterPort(0, &iokitPort);
CFDictionaryRef serviceName = IOServiceNameMatching("AppleARMPMUCharger");

io_service_t service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(iokitPort, serviceName);

if (service == 0)
   return nil;

kern_return_t status = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(service,
                                                             &properties,
                                                             kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                             kNilOptions);

IOObjectRelease(service);
```

Comment: If i use IOKit, app will reject in appstore??

Comment: It may be rejected yes

Comment: I dont want to fetch battery state and battery percentage , i just want to fetch cycleCount