# iOS 12 – The simplest way to obtain battery cycle count for iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, battery

I know that public API at the moment allows obtain only two useful properties for battery: `batteryLevel` and `batteryState`. Even after WWDC 2018 there's no any changes.

```
let batteryLevel = UIDevice.current.batteryLevel  /* from 0 to 1 */
let batteryState = UIDevice.current.batteryState  /* four states */
```

What's the simplest way to obtain **battery cycle count** in iOS 12 using free private API or Apple's official API?

P.S. `UIDeviceListener` isn't working in iOS 10/11/12. Also it's written in Objective-C.

Comment: You can [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36949252)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the release of iOS 10, Apple has cut off access to battery details for third-party apps in the App Store, making these apps completely useless.

***At the moment there's no way to obtain `battery cycle count` for iPhone in iOS 12 using public APIs***. Even `Console` app in macOS Mojave 10.14 doesn't show cycle counts for iPhone.

So, the only robust way to see cycle counts is to install ***`coconutBattery`*** macOS application.

[image]

P.S. `UIDeviceListener` doesn't work in iOS 10 and higher ([read this SO post](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/45374039/)).

Comment: Well, how does coconutBattery read battery cycle count for ios device? There should be some api or direct access to read that value, right?